# Newton's 2nd law of motion and mass-energy equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity, kinematics, mass-energy

According to the mass-energy equation
$E=mc^2$, so $m=\frac{E}{c^2}$, but according to Newton 2nd law of motion $F=ma$, so $m=\frac{F}{a}$. Therefore $\frac{E}{c^2}=\frac{F}{a}$, or $E=\frac{Fc^2}{a}$. Does this mean that there is no mass?
If there is mass then how can we find mass?

Comment: This is a good example of how physics isn't pure math. You need to know what your equations mean and what it means when you use them the way you do.

Comment: thanks but how can we find mass?

Comment: What do you mean by find mass?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot physically get rid of mass through mathematical manipulations. Also, just because through substitutions you remove a variable from your equations does not mean that it is not physically important. As for what you use, let's look at the two main equations.

Newton's second law $F=ma$ means that if a net force $F$ acts on an object of mass $m$, then it will have an acceleration of $a$.

The equation $E=mc^2$ comes from special relativity, and it says that the rest energy $E$ of an object of mass $m$ is equal to $mc^2$, where $c$ is the speed of light. Since $m$ and $c$ are assumed to be invariant quantities, the rest energy of an object is also invariant.

Now, through substitutions you arrive at $E=\frac{Fc^2}{a}$. There are some issues here mixing up Newtonian mechanics with relativity and acceleration, so we would need to be careful with defining reference frames, relative velocities, etc. I don't think this is the point of the question though, so I won't get into that. Therefore, ignoring all of that, all you really have done is just combined two equations to say

> If I apply a net force $F$ to an object and it has an acceleration $a$, then the rest energy of this object is given by $E=\frac{Fc^2}{a}$, where $c$ is the speed of light.

This doesn't mean we have "gotten rid of mass", unless you just mean our equation does not explicitly involve mass, which is true. But how $F$ and $a$ relate still depend on the mass of the object.

An analogy from 1D motion under constant acceleration can be made. An object undergoing constant acceleration $a$ will have position $x$ and velocity $v$ as functions of time obtained through integration as
$$x=x_0+v_0t+\frac12at^2$$
$$v=v_0+at$$
with initial position $x_0$ and initial velocity $v_0$

However, we can combine these equations to eliminate explicit time dependence
$$v^2=v_0^2+2a(x-x_0)$$

Does this mean that suddenly time is irrelevant? It does not. The position and velocity still evolve over time, but we can use the equations to tell us how these time evolutions relate based on other relevant parameters of the system. Just because a variable is not explicitly in an equation does not mean the missing variable is irrelevant for the system the equation describes.

Comment: Also, the OP's equation is only approximately correct, and the approximation fails badly at relativistic speeds... unless $m$ is relativistic mass, and the acceleration is in the same direction as the body's velocity, but let's not go there. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes I completely agree